# Why hazelcast-mancenter doesn't see any cache statistics?

Tags: hazelcast

I have problem with hazelcast-mancenter to getting working
I have distributed cache configured and working: spring query cache and hibernate cache, but i cannot see any cache stats in managment center - https://i.stack.imgur.com/asg3g.jpg

My config:

```
    <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:group name="dev"/>
            <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="false" multicast-group="224.2.2.3" multicast-port="54327"/>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
            <hz:management-center enabled="true" scripting-enabled="true" url="http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter"  update-interval="3"/>

            <hz:properties>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.jmx">true</hz:property>
            </hz:properties>
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>
```

Comment: Try examining `hazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects()` as this will list which caches/maps exist and their names. This will help confirm if the caches are actually there and stats are missing, or the objects are missing so no stats are relevant. This might also be relevant for Hibernate https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/issues/6

Comment: Afaik, you should enable statistics on `IMap/ICache` to see their stats on management center. Can you confirm that statistics are enabled on their relevant configurations?